# Calculate industry concentration based on four biggest numbers

Tags: file, stata

I am trying to find the four biggest numbers of a variable in Stata, as I want to calculate the industry concentration of different groups based on sales. I have firms sales from multiple years and the firms belong to different groups based on industries and countries.

Thus, I would like to find:

> industry concentration = (4 biggest sales-values of a year of one industry-&-country-group) / sum of all sales for one year of the industry-&-country-group)

I have about `10000` firms for about `10` years:

```
firms   country   year   industry   sales  
    a       usa      1          1     300  
    a       usa      2          1    4000  
    b       ger      1          1     200  
    b       ger      2          1     400  
    c       usa      1          1     100  
    c       usa      2          1     300  
    d       usa      1          1     400  
    d       usa      2          1     200  
    e       usa      1          1    7000  
    e       usa      2          1     900  
    f       ger      1          2     100  
    f       ger      2          2     700  
    h       ger      1          2     700  
    h       ger      2          2     600
```

I know how to find the sum of sales per industry-country-year-group:

```
bysort country industry year: egen sum_sales = sum(sales)
```

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the four biggest is

```
bysort country industry year (sales): generate four_biggest_sales = sales[_N] + ///
                                      sales[_N-1] + sales[_N-2] + sales[_N-3]
```

provided that no values of `sales` are missing. If there are only three values then you'd need

```
max(0, sales[_N-3])
```

with similar corrections for the cases of two values, one value or none.

This all follows from basic syntax for the `by` prefix. See [this article on Stata Journal](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004) for a tutorial.

If there are missings, then they can be segregated by

```
generate isnotmiss = !missing(sales) 
bysort isnotmiss country industry year (sales): generate four_biggest_sales = sales[_N] + ///
                                                sales[_N-1] + sales[_N-2] + sales[_N-3]
```

Comment: thanks a lot Nick. great help and really quick reply. I'll try it out in an hour.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NickC. I still have a small question. I am sorry if this is too easy or seems stupid, but I am new to stata and cannot find an easy answer.
As I do have a lot of missing values, I dropped the rows with missing ones by opening a new dta (window). is there another possibility to keep working on the same dta while doing the calculation of gen-4-biggest-sales? Thanks

Comment: See above for more comments.