# Generating a variable only including the top 4 firms with largest sales

Tags: stata

My question is very related to the question below:

- [Calculate industry concentration in Stata based on four biggest numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771069/calculate-industry-concentration-in-stata-based-on-four-biggest-numbers)

I want to generate a variable only including the top `4` firms with largest sales and exclude the rest.

In other words the new variable will only have values of the `4` firms with largest sales in a given industry for a given year and the rest will be `.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
bysort year (invest) : gen largest4 = cond(_n < _N - 3, ., invest) 
sort year invest 
list year largest4 if largest4 < . in 1/40, sepby(year) 

     +-----------------+
     | year   largest4 |
     |-----------------|
  7. | 1935      39.68 |
  8. | 1935      40.29 |
  9. | 1935      209.9 |
 10. | 1935      317.6 |
     |-----------------|
 17. | 1936      50.73 |
 18. | 1936      72.76 |
 19. | 1936      355.3 |
 20. | 1936      391.8 |
     |-----------------|
 27. | 1937      74.24 |
 28. | 1937       77.2 |
 29. | 1937      410.6 |
 30. | 1937      469.9 |
     |-----------------|
 37. | 1938       51.6 |
 38. | 1938      53.51 |
 39. | 1938      257.7 |
 40. | 1938      262.3 |
     +-----------------+
```

If you had missing values, they would sort to the end of each block and mess up the results.

So you need a trick more:

```
generate OK = !missing(invest) 
bysort OK year (invest) : gen Largest4 = cond(_n < _N - 3, ., invest) if OK 
sort year invest 
list year Largest4 if Largest4 < . in 1/40, sepby(year)
```

With this example, which you can run, there are no missing values and the results are the same.